# How to get Show segue's timing function and duration

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I want to add an animation to my `UIView` so that it will move along with show segue. How do I get the default timing function and duration for show segue?

Here is my code:

```
let transition=CATransition()
transition.duration=0.4
transition.type=kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
myUIView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
```

However my view's entering animation is not completely synchronized with the show segue's animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `UIViewController`'s `transitionCoordinator` and call `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` which is documented in [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/). `viewWillAppear` is usually a good place to do this.

You can then run any animations you want along with the default animation.

Comment: Thanks this is easy to use.